History of extension problem of abelian groups
Given a short exact sequence of abelian groups:
$$ 0 \to A \to X \to B \to 0 $$
If we know the structures of $A$ and $B$, what information can we deduce about the structure of $X$?
In simpler terms, if we know the subgroup $A$ and the quotient group $X/A$ of $X$, how can we reconstruct the structure of $X$? I believe many of us have wondered about this question when first encountering the concept of quotient groups in abelian group theory.
This problem is essentially about the extensions of abelian groups, which has been well understood. In fact, the equivalence classes of short exact sequences of the form above correspond to the group $\text{Ext}^1(A,B)$, which also has an abelian group structure. This seems to me like a "classic" problem.
To understand the definition of $\text{Ext}^1(A,B)$, we need to study homological algebra. Indeed, one of the motivations for learning homological algebra for me was to understand how to solve the abelian group extension problem, much like why one might study Galois groups to prove the insolvability of the general quintic equation.
However, despite having studied homological algebra (using Weibel's Introduction to Homological Algebra), the definition and properties of $\text{Ext}$, and how it is applied to solve the abelian group extension problem, I still don't fully understand what happened. From my perspective, solving the abelian group extension problem seems like a minor byproduct of the grand framework of homological algebra.
In other words, if homological algebra had not yet been introduced and the functor $\text{Ext}$ did not exist, and I were just trying to solve the abelian group extension problem, I would have no idea where to start. If a future mathematician presented me with a solution using homological algebra, I would be utterly surprised, wondering why they thought of constructing all these tools. This seems quite different from my experience with Galois theory, where at least I understood that the goal was to study permutations of roots.
On the other hand, in Weibel's textbook, the section on abelian group extensions mentions that even without the Ext functor, the concept of Baer sums can be used to give a group structure to the short exact sequence. This suggests that before homological algebra, the Abelian group corresponding to the equivalence class of the extension problem (i.e., $\text{Ext}^1(A,B)$) was already known, but perhaps the methods to compute it were not fully developed.
My Question:
Thus, I would like to understand how the abelian group extension problem was studied before the advent of homological algebra, and what concrete results were obtained. How did mathematicians come to realize that homological algebra could solve this problem? One further question I have is how the abelian group extension problem could be solved using more elementary methods, without relying on the full framework of homological algebra, though this might not be the most appropriate question for this forum.

A detailed account of the early history of group extensions is given in chapter 9 of Nicholson's 1993 PhD thesis (freely available from Oxford's research archive). Later, cohomological, developments are described by MacLane himself in Group extensions for 45 years (1988).
Betti accidentally discovered semidirect products and thought about more general group extensions in 1852, but was hampered but the absence of the worked out concept of the quotient group. So was Jordan in 1860-70s. The formulation of the problem and first systematic work on group extensions was done by Hölder in 1890s, who by then had a good grasp of quotient groups. He was apparently influenced by examples in Klein's Lectures on the Icosahedron that already talked about "extended groups".
In his paper, Die Gruppen der Ordnungen $p^3, pq^2, pqr, p^4$ (1893) Hölder developed some general theory of constructing groups, related it to the notion of automorphism he introduced, and considered extensions by a cyclic group. Hölder calls automorphism "ein Isomorphismus einer Gruppe in sich" (Moore discovered them independently in 1895), and they are the centerpiece of his methodology. Multiplication on the extended group is described in terms of automorphisms of the original one, and he calculated automorphisms mostly by considering their effect on a set of generators. The follow-up paper Bildung zusammengesetzter Gruppen (1895) develops many specific examples of group extensions and calculates automorphism groups, but Hölder focuses on extensions by simple rather than Abelian groups, and he was far from thinking about, let alone characterizing, all extensions.
That step was made 30 years later by Schreier, who is often considered "the founder" of group extension theory, in his 1923 doctoral dissertation published in two papers in 1926, Über die Erweiterung von Gruppen I and II. Schreier's approach is much more abstract, in the spirit of modern algebra, albeit not homological algebra, and he did focus on Abelian extensions. His work was continued by Baer in Erweiterung von Gruppen und ihren Isomorphismen (1934), who proved that those themselves form a group. But in 1940-s Eilenberg and Mac Lane completely reshaped the subject after "an accidental observation that the groups obtained by Steenrod were identical with some groups that occur in the purely algebraic theory of extensions of groups" Eilenberg-MacLane, Group Extensions and Homology (1942).
Some more history from Nicholson:

"One sometimes reads, for example in [Zassenhaus 1949, 94], that Schreier's paper of 1926 presents a solution of the extension problem... It would be fairer to say that Schreier set out the theory, but that the problem remains unsolved, despite much effort in subsequent years, including
especially the development of the cohomology of groups... It was in fact Otto Hölder who first posed the extension problem in full generality and began a systematic attack on it [1895a], having laid foundations for such a theory in [1893].


[...] Nevertheless, no-one else took up this work for another thirty years and the ideas Holder had developed were all but forgotten... The two papers on extension theory published by Schreier in 1926 are reproductions of the first and second halves of his doctoral dissertation, completed at Vienna in 1923... Schreier's approach to and development of the theory
of extensions seems to follow on directly from that of Otto Hölder: much of Hölder's
methodology was borrowed by Schreier. The difference between their work is that
Schreier drew out each idea to its logical conclusion, whereas Hölder had been motivated
initially by the wish to classify particular sorts of groups... The change in outlook from the nineteenth to the twentieth centuries can clearly be seen in Schreier's papers: he approached the problem from a completely abstract standpoint.


[...] What was Schreier's achievement towards the establishing of a theory of group extensions?.. Extending a group by means of an abelian group: this is investigated by assuming
that the factors of a direct product... are cyclic (of finite or infinite order). As before, Schreier calculated the conditions under which this may happen and the defining relations for the extension... In 1934 Reinhold Baer carried
on the work of Schreier in studying extensions of abelian groups, and proved that the
extension classes themselves form an abelian group. Then Marshall Hall Jr. [1938]
investigated what he referred to as 'central extensions' and dealt with the equivalence
of factor sets, amongst other things.


[...] Group extension theory was transformed during the 1940s by the introduction of ideas
that had their conception in algebraic topology. This study of cohomological extension
theory was begun by Eilenberg and Mac Lane, whose results were first published in
[1942]:`This paper originated from an accidental observation that the groups obtained
by Steenrod were identical with some groups that occur in the purely algebraic theory
of extensions of groups...' It is unlikely that Hölder would recognise a modern (cohomological) introduction to this theory as the fruition of the ideas he had during the 1890s."

